# I copied code from fiddle and dreamweaver did not reponse as well the javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to use the code that been share at fiddle just now and when try it on dreamweaver it didnt work as well. I want use the code for my final project. I did research recently and this code was look easist than the other. Still new in js, css and html.

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
var counter = 10;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 10 seconds.";
var id;

downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);

id = setInterval(function () {
    counter--;
    if (counter < 0) {
        newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: #ddcccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: small;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="b.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="c.css" />

<a href="downloadFile.zip" id="download" class="button">Download the file...</a>
```

Comment: And did you place the script after the elements in the DOM

Comment: basically i'll import the script first to at the top of html as and use the function usually. Familiar with DOM but I didnt know how to use it. I learn this language mostly by myself. sorry if bad english here. im trying to gain knowledge. (: